# How do I mirror my pose for symmetry

Tags: rigging

I'm working with a face rig. When I rotate one bone in pose mode, I would like the same bone on the other side of the face to automatically rotate in symmetrical manner. Is this possible to do in Blender?

Answer (score 2):

X-axis mirror will accomplish this for you. Go into edit mode, and under the options tab of the tool shelf you'll find the checkbox. See the GIF for a  visual.[image]

Comment: Does this work in Pose mode though?